# why does nrc emotions show positive emotions when they are actually negative? R

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I'm conducting a sentiment analysis using reviews from the below website.

https://www.yelp.com/biz/24th-st-pizzeria-san-antonio?osq=Worst+Restaurant

It's clear customers are unhappy, however, when getting the emotions, it continuously shows positive feelings. Is there any data pre-processing that I missed or an issue with the code I'm using? How can I get a more accurate overview of the emotions? I looked for other packages that allow me to graph various emotions, but it seems syuzhet is the only one with this capability.

```
library(syuzhet)
library(plotly)

df=read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/Examples/main/reviews.csv')

sentReviews <- iconv(df$Text)

# get user emotions using the NRC dictionary
nrc_emotions <- get_nrc_sentiment(sentReviews)
head(nrc_emotions)

# Build a df for emotions using column sums
emo_bar = colSums(nrc_emotions)
emo_sum = data.frame(count=emo_bar, emotion=names(emo_bar))
emo_sum

# Prepare to graph by ordering from highest to lowest
emo_sum$emotion = factor(emo_sum$emotion, levels=emo_sum$emotion[order(emo_sum$count, decreasing = TRUE)])


plot_ly(emo_sum, x=~emotion, y=~count, type="bar", color=~emotion) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title=""), showlegend=FALSE,
         title="Distribution of emotion categories")
```

Here is the output from the graph. This makes no sense since the negative reviews make up over 90% of the reviews.
[image: graph of emotions]

Answer (score 0):

There are several packages that can do sentiment analysis, like `sentimentr`. Other packages like `tidytext` and `quanteda` (and even `tm`) can be used when you use then nrc dictionary as a lookup table.

Using `syuzhet` and the `get_nrc_sentiment`, you don't get a sentiment score. You get a table telling you which word of the nrc it found in the text and how often. And in the end you get a count of the negative words and the positive words.

The first six lines of the reviews show this:

```
head(nrc_emotions)
  anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative positive
1     0            0       0    0   1       0        0     1        1        1
2     2            2       1    1   1       0        1     2        4        3
3     4            2       4    3   2       1        2     2        6        4
4     2            1       2    1   3       2        1     3        4        3
5     1            2       1    1   1       1        2     1        1        3
6     1            0       2    2   1       2        1     1        5        3
```

If you look at the second review, you have a total 4 negative and 3 positive words. To get a sentiment out of this you can do several calculations, 1 just deduct the negatives from the positives. Anything that is below 0 is a negative review, with the bigger the number the more negative it is. Or you can use this, but divide it by to sum of the positives and negatives to give you a score between 1 and -1. The closer it gets to -1 the more negative the review.

```
library(dplyr)

nrc_emotions %>% 
  mutate(sentiment1 = positive - negative, 
         sentiment2 = (positive - negative) / (positive + negative)) %>% 
  head()

  anger anticipation disgust fear joy sadness surprise trust negative positive sentiment1 sentiment2
1     0            0       0    0   1       0        0     1        1        1          0  0.0000000
2     2            2       1    1   1       0        1     2        4        3         -1 -0.1428571
3     4            2       4    3   2       1        2     2        6        4         -2 -0.2000000
4     2            1       2    1   3       2        1     3        4        3         -1 -0.1428571
5     1            2       1    1   1       1        2     1        1        3          2  0.5000000
6     1            0       2    2   1       2        1     1        5        3         -2 -0.2500000
```

Of course just using `head(get_sentiment(sentReviews, method = "nrc"))` from the syuzhet package will return the same scores as using positive - negative.

But do check out the several sentiment scores you get with the different methods via
`syuzhet` and even `sentimentr` or other packages like `sentiment.ai` and `tardis`. All of them give slightly different sentiment scores depending on the scoring functions used, are valence shifts (i.e negations (words like not), amplifiers (very), etc etc) taking into account or not. And is the sentiment analysis suited for the job. Some are not really suited for tweets others are.

**Update:**

Let's look at the scores for record 5. Here you can see that the stars given do not match what you see if you use a sentiment dictionary.  It has a 1 star review, but a positive nrc sentiment (1 neg, 3 pos). See below which words result in this score.

```
dat = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/Examples/main/reviews.csv')

library(tidytext)

# using record 5 as an example
dat[5,] %>% 
  tidytext::unnest_tokens(output = "word", input = Text) %>% 
  inner_join(nrc) %>% 
  filter(sentiment %in% c("positive", "negative"))

Joining, by = "word"
       Date  Rating       word sentiment
1 8/21/2022 1 star       bitch  negative
2 8/21/2022 1 star      daring  positive
3 8/21/2022 1 star  personable  positive
4 8/21/2022 1 star        deal  positive
```

You can see that the nrc dataset results in a positive score based on these 4 words. Over the whole review set that explains the positive and negative values you get. The nrc dataset does not take valence shifts, negations or (de-)amplifiers into account. This is one of the reasons why you see the results you see in your question. Read the P.S. at the bottom.

Now if you use different scoring algorithms you get different outcomes.

Using syuzet:

```
sentReviews <- iconv(dat$Text)

get_sentiment(sentReviews[5], method = "syuzhet")
[1] -0.65
get_sentiment(sentReviews[5], method = "bing")
[1] -2
get_sentiment(sentReviews[5], method = "nrc")
[1] 2
```

sentimentr:

```
sentimentr::sentiment_by(sentReviews[5])
   element_id word_count        sd ave_sentiment
1:          1        132 0.2136088   -0.06451112
```

sentiment.ai

```
library(sentiment.ai)

# install_sentiment.ai()

init_sentiment.ai()
x <- sentiment_score(sentReviews[5]))
as_tibble(x)
# A tibble: 1 × 1
   value
   <dbl>
1 -0.766
```

P.S.:

Always read the [Emotion Lexicons: Ethics and Data Statement](http://saifmohammad.com/WebDocs/EmoLex-Ethics-Data-Statement.pdf) to see what limitations, errors and other restrictions apply. If available.

Also always check how the dataset was built, which rules were applied and any other consideration. See [this post](https://koaning.io/posts/go-emotions/) about the GoEmotions dataset.

And for the algorithms, read up on how they were created, if there is any critique on them and if they are actually useful (or meant) for the dataset you are using.

Comment: I see. I corrected my post. I am graphing the emotions and I'm confused why it keeps showing more positive emotions, even though it's clear there are more negative ones. I want to get a more accurate overview of the emotions. It currently shows that 645 negative emotions and 673 positive emotions. Since most of the reviews are negative, we should expect a significant difference between the negative and positive emotions.

Comment: @bandcar, Welcome to sentiment analysis based on purely on text. See an update in the answer.